# Fast way to search for lists in list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a list of sentences and a list of queries. The queries have distinct space-separated words, I have to find the sentences having all the queries and print the indexes of the sentences. 
**Example:**

```
3
hey how are you
how do you do
how are you doing
2
how
how are
```

**Output:**

```
0 1 2
0 2
```

The input structure is something like this:

```
sentences = ['hey how are you' , 'how do you do' , 'how are you doing']
queries = ['how', 'how are']
```

I have been using O(n^3) algorithm but that's very slow and giving me a TLE. Is there a faster way to do it, maybe regex but I haven't been able to figure out how to build the expression?

The input size is limited to 10^4.

My code :

```
def textQueries(sentences, queries):
def maptoDict(sentence):
    d = {}
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word not in d.keys():
            d[word] = 1
        else:
            d[word] += 1
    return d
s = list(map(maptoDict,sentences))
q = list(set(query.split()) for query in queries)
for query in q:
    res = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if query.issubset(set(s[i].keys())):
            res.append(i)
    if not len(res):
        res.append(-1)
    for r in res:
        print(r, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: You haven't shown a list in your example. Please don't leave us guessing what the structure is for either list.

Comment: Your example does not show a `list` or a `list of queries` it just shows what could be a set of words in a `.txt` file, Please provide both `list`s and whatever `code` you have attempted.

Comment: While we're at it, you don't specify if the query words have to appear in sequence, or in exact order, or just anywhere? That is, does `'how are'` require the words `how` and `are` anywhere in the sentence, or `how...are` in order but maybe with other words between, or `how are` exactly?

Comment: Your code formatting seems off, could you edit the question & kindly correct it? See here for more info on formatting code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `O(max(n)^2)` will be the time complexity at the least where `n` is max length among individual sentences. You can store all subarrays in a map and then do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot better. But please try to fix ths indentation. If you need help with that, let us know.

Comment: Giving us an update would be nice.

Comment: I tried all the given solutions. TLE still happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store each subarray of strings in a `map`. The `value` of the `key` in the `map` will be a list(of indices of course). Below is the pseudocode-

**Pseudocode:**

```
    Map<string,list> map
    for each_sentence in sentence_list:
        words = each_sentence.split("\\s")
           for i = 0 to words.length():
               for j=i to words.length():
                 subword = string from i to j
                 if map.containsKey(subword):
                     map.get(subword).add(each_sentence's index)
                 else:
                    map.put(subword,new list(each_sentence's index))

   for each_query in query_list:
       print map.containsKey(each_query) ? map.get(each_query) : -1
```

Time Complexity: O(n^2) where `n` is the maximum length of a sentence among all sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Python supports the data structure called a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). You can post-process your sentences to produce a map of words to sets.

That is, a map like:

```
word_in_sentences["how"] = set(0, 1, 2)
```

With that data structure, you can compute the set intersection of all the query words. This would give you a set that contains all the words in the query, with no concern about the order of the words.

Once you filter the sentences down to that smaller group, doing whatever ordering search should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I formatted the output so you could trace the loop to see how each item is retrieved. You can use the elements of this to just print the `index` if you'd like but I wanted you to see how to get the things you are requesting.

```
sentences = ['hey how are you', 'how do you do', 'how are you doing']
queries = ['how', 'how are']

for i, items in enumerate(sentences):
   for j in queries:
        if j in items:
            print(f"Query '{j}' is in Sentence {i}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 sent_find.py 
> Query 'how' is in Sentence 0
> Query 'how are' is in Sentence 0
> Query 'how' is in Sentence 1
> Query 'how' is in Sentence 2
> Query 'how are' is in Sentence 2
> ```

This will get that basic output:

```
sentences = ['hey how are you', 'how do you do', 'how are you doing']
queries = ['how', 'how are']

for i in queries:
    for j, items in enumerate(sentences):
        if i in items:
            print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

**Output**

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 sent_find.py 
0 1 2 
0 2
```